# Java: KeyListener being interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, keylistener

Good Day (or night) Everyone! 
I was lately developing a little game and decided to use javax.swing (basically JFrame stuff xD) and KeyListener. 
Now, my basic game loop was a thread, so it went smoothly with my KeyListener. 
So now I was able to get input from the KeyListener, process the input, and make an output. 
But then I had to make a function that would draw all the things that I wanted drawn on the JFrame. 
This took quite a bit of the computing power I had and made my game slower. But that wasn't the problem. 
The problem occurred when I had to use that function multiple times almost at once, which didn't let the KeyListener run at all.

So now my big question is, what would be the preferred method to prevent the interruption?

Can I use some sort of Thread but for voids to prevent this?

Big Thanks from Me to Whoever solves my question! :D

Comment: Read about [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: The `KeyListener` and the painting occur on the same thread - also Swing is single threaded and NOT thread safe, so you need to take that into consideration when using seperate threads to compute and interact with the UI.  You might also consider using the key bindings API as it will solve focus related issues

Comment: A common mistake is to read images from files in a paint method.  If you’re doing that, read the images once in your constructor and store them in private fields.  Avoiding file reads will make your painting considerably faster.

Comment: 1. It seems that indeed I have to use the Event Dispatch Thread, but how do I activate it?

Comment: 2. VGR, I already opened all my images as soon as the program starts, thus that cant be the problem....